# Pygame Object Movement With Slopes/Angles

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, angle

I'm trying to create a game that when the player clicks, the player shoots a
projectile on the same path of the point clicked. My code works fine so far, except that the farther away the player clicks, the faster it moves. Here is the code:

```py
class Projectile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    x2 = 0
    y2 = 0
    slope_x = 0
    slope_y = 0
    attack_location = ()
    slope = 0

    def __init__(self,image):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 390
        self.rect.y = 289
        self.attack_location = (mouse_x,mouse_y)
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        self.x2 = self.attack_location[0]
        self.y2 = self.attack_location[1]
        self.slope_y = self.y2 - 300
        self.slope_x = self.x2 - 400

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += (self.slope_x) / 15
        self.rect.y += (self.slope_y) / 15
```

My code is a bit sloppy and simple, but I'd like to know if there's a way to set the speed constant or maybe even use trigonometry for the movement of the projectile on an angle.

Actually, I have managed to normalize the vector, but the projectile comes out as if it is from (0,0), but the character's position is (400,300). I'm wondering if there's any way to make it so the vector starts at (400,300), or if there's another solution to my original problem. Thanks! Here is the code:

```py
    def __init__(self,image):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 0
        self.rect.y = 0
        self.attack_location = (mouse_x,mouse_y)
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        self.x2 = self.attack_location[0]
        self.y2 = self.attack_location[1]
        self.d = math.sqrt(((self.x2)**2) + ((self.y2)**2))
        self.slope_x = self.x2 / self.d
        self.slope_y = self.y2 / self.d

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += (self.slope_x) * 10
        self.rect.y += (self.slope_y) * 10​
```

Comment: As you click further away `x2, y2` get bigger (or smaller). That means `slope_y, slope_x` get bigger. That means the increment you increase `rect.x, rect.y` is larger. Therefor anytime you update the missile position it is increment by a smaller or larger amount based on where you clicked.

Comment: I understand, I just wanted to know if there's any way to prevent that. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to normalize the direction vector.
Something like this:

```
d = math.sqrt(mouse_x * mouse_x + mouse_y * mouse_y)
self.slope_x = mouse_x / d - 300
self.slope_y = mouse_y / d - 400
```